# Does this tree class allow fastest execution (memory not important) in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

In Java, is the following `Tree` class with `List<Tree> children` in each node the fastest way for further navigation of the tree?

```
public class Tree {

    private int data;

    private List<Tree> children = new ArrayList<Tree>();

    // operations to insert and navigate Tree nodes

}
```

I just add new Tree objects to the appropriate array of children and so the entire tree expands. Don't use deletion of elements because I use them to navigate the tree all the time through the algorithm.

And how should this Tree data structure change if I do insertion and navigation as above plus deletion of nodes? Then maybe change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`?

There lots of examples elsewhere but there is no comparison and so without enough experience I can not trust to choose any Tree implementation. That's why I'm asking some advice to find the best data structure (for fastest execution, memory is irrelevant) for two described situations (1. insertion/navigation; 2. insertion/navigation/removal).

**EDIT**: Can you say what you are not using the built in TreeMap or TreeSet? Because I'm studying Algorithms in general and it is hard to read builtin Java classes as they contain lots of code (checks, conversion, useless functions) that is not needed in understanding the basic operations of the algorithms.

Comment: Can you say what you are not using the built in TreeMap or TreeSet?

Comment: Does it really need to be the absolute fastest? If the number of children is fixed and small (eg a binary tree) then a separate field for each child is probably very fast. An array is probably second-best for that, and best if the number of children is not fixed and you're not changing it frequently. Of course you should test all of those to find out how fast they actually are and pick the best one.

Comment: But an ArrayList, like you have now, will be almost as fast as any of them and much easier to write code with.

Answer (score 0):

What is the usecase? If you want add-remove-traverse and not any fancy tree functionality, just use a ArrayList! Why Tree?